# Generate flv, mpg or some other movie format from an ActionScript movie clip

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flv

I am working on a Flex application/game where a lot of UIComponents are moved around on a canvas.

I would like to "record" an flv movie of the movement on the canvas. Is there anyway this can be accomplished ?

I essentially want my users to be able to record small flv videos of their games to be uploaded on youtube.

Any ideas or suggestions about how to do this ?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something similar. Did you used a streaming server to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [SimpleFlvWriter (for AIR)](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/?p=14). You may modify it to get a non-AIR version. But memory management will be an issue since BitmapData will take up a lot of memory... It may be possible for a few seconds flv but definite not for several minutes.

Usually we stream things to a Flash server (eg. Flash Media Server, [Red5](http://www.red5.org/)) and let the server create the flv. But you need to find a way to convert the screen captures to `NetStream`. Or you may find other server side technology that can create flv from sequence of `BitmapData`. But in anyway it will consume a lot of bandwidth.

An alternative I can think of, is to save all the game commands(in XML, or other text format) and send it to the server. And you write a program in server-side to generate the flv from only the game commands. But it will be the most difficult solution to be implemented.